# Swift nested type hides outer type

Tags: swift

In Swift, is there any way of referring to an global type T from inside a class that has an nested class T defined within it?

This is a minimal example of my actual problem:

```
class Dialog : GameView {
}

class Quest {
    struct Dialog : QuestStep {
        func enter(){
            showMessage(Dialog()) // Here I want to instantiate the GameView Dialog, not the QuestStep Dialog.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try what ever your module is called and the class i.e `MyModule.Dialog()` for the inner I think you should be able to do `Quest.Dialog()`